# Bluetooth programming with iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, bluetooth, connection

Is it possible to make a connection from iPhone/iPad/iPod to Mac via Bluetooth legally without breaking Apple's AppStore rules within `SDK`?

I know that connection between iOS devices is relatively simple using `GameKit`. How about connection to a Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it can not be done...